# What is the difference between an array storing objects and an arraylist?

Tags: arrays, arraylist

I am quite a novice programmer so I need so help understanding the difference between arrays storing objects and array lists. Here I have created both but can someone explain what is the difference? Is it that one can store only reference while the other can't or something else?

```
public class Animal {

int mass;
String color;
String sound;

Animal (int m, String c, String s)
{
    mass=m;
    color=c;
    sound=s;
}
```

}

import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Main {
public static void main (String Args [])
{
    Animal cat = new Animal(10,"orange","mew");
    Animal dog = new Animal(20,"black","Woof");
    Animal cow = new Animal(400,"white","muuu");

    ArrayList <Animal> a = new ArrayList<Animal>(3);
    a.add(cat);
    a.add(dog);
    a.add(cow);

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int mass;
    String color;
    String sound;

    System.out.println("Enter the mass, color and sound of each animal");
    Animal [] array = new Animal[3];
    for (int q=0; q<3; q++)
    {
        mass=scan.nextInt();
        color=scan.nextLine();
        sound=scan.nextLine();
        array[q] = new Animal(mass,color,sound);
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

@jcm there are a couple of differences between `Array` and `ArrayList`. that you can find it from here [Array Vs ArrayList](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/array-vs-arraylist-in-java/).

Now as per your question about reference is, ArrayList and Array both stores the `reference` of the `object` only. `none` of them stores the `actual object`. actual objects are stored in the `heap memory`.

for more details, you can check this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18855639/what-does-arraylist-actually-stores-references-to-objects-or-actual-objects).